# check user input is an integer java

Tags: java

I want to check that the input the user presses is an integer or a float, but I'm getting an error: `incompatible operand types int and string`. I'm using processing, so when the user presses the return key, I want to check that the value that was just entered was numerical.

```
void keyPressed() {
  // If the return key is pressed, save the String and clear it
  if (key == '\n' ) {
    if(input == Integer.parseInt(input)){
    saved = input;
    // A String can be cleared by setting it equal to ""
    input = ""; 
    }
  }
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt()` returns an `Int` (or throws an exception).  You're trying to compare that `Int` with the `String` named `input`.

Comment: i know that. i need a fix. the  user can press any key. but i need to check if that key was an integer or float

Comment: @soong it's an `int` not an `Int`

Comment: @Hailey sorry been doing a lot of Scala lately!  It is indeed `int`

Answer (score 2):

There's an "is digit" function for characters that you can use if you turn your strings into character arrays.

```
void keyPressed() {
    // If the return key is pressed, save the String and clear it
    if (key == '\n') {
        char[] temp = input.toCharArray();
        for (char x : temp) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(x)) {
                // do something, this is not a number!
                // you can return if you don't want to save the string if it's not a number
                input = ""; // you may also want to clear the input here
                return;
            }
        }
        // other code here, such as saving the string
        saved = input;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do your code this way which is not recommended you can do

```
if (key == '\n' ) {
   try {
      int value = Integer.parseInt(input)
      // Is an integer
   } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      // Not an integer
   }
}
```

The proper way to do is to check the char for each in the string and make sure each is numeric.

Comment: Exception type is `NumberFormatException`

Comment: This gives the same error that OP has - `incompatible operand types int and string`

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Scanner:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
if(!sc.hasNextInt()) return false;
sc.nextInt();
return !sc.hasNext(); // should be done
```

Or you could just go `input.matches("\\d+");`

Answer (score 0):

Integer.parseInt(input) is converting input to an int, then you are checking if the String == the int.

```
void keyPressed() {
    if (key == '\n' ) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(input);
            saved = input;
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            //ignore input
        }
    // A String can be cleared by setting it equal to ""
    input = ""; 
    }
  }
```

Should work better.

Comment: This is wrong. `saved` is clearly a string as well, and doing this results in the exact same error OP was having.

Comment: @Aify Yeah, I misunderstood what OP was trying to do, edited to fix it.

Comment: 1) saved == input is a statement with no effect. 2) this is now essentially a copy of Daniel Hu's answer.

Comment: I fixed the ==. as for the similarities, oh well.